# How to write data from queue to MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-kafka, queue

I have a running zookeeper + kafka and I am successfully sending tweets to the kafka producer. The tweets are taken from a queue:

```
queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(10000);
public void run() {
        client.connect();
        try (Producer<Long, String> producer = getProducer()) {
            while (true) {
                Tweet tweet = gson.fromJson(queue.take(), Tweet.class);
                System.out.printf("Fetched tweet id %d\n", tweet.getId());
                long key = tweet.getId();
                String msg = tweet.toString();
                ProducerRecord<Long, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(KafkaConfiguration.TOPIC, key, msg);
                producer.send(record, callback);


            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            client.stop();
        }
```

My question is how to write the already received object (the class Tweet) to MongoDB? I have the configuration setup like this on my localhost:

```
//MongoDB config
    int port_no = 27017;
    String host_name = "localhost", db_name = "bigdata", db_coll_name = "twitter";

    // Mongodb connection string.
    String client_url = "mongodb://" + host_name + ":" + port_no + "/" + db_name;
    MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(client_url);

    // Connecting to the mongodb server using the given client uri.
    MongoClient mongo_client = new MongoClient(uri);

    // Fetching the database from the mongodb.
    MongoDatabase db = mongo_client.getDatabase(db_name);

    // Fetching the collection from the mongodb.
    MongoCollection<Document> coll = db.getCollection(db_coll_name);
```

Is there some way to deserialize it with JSON? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [Kafka Connect MongoDB Sink Connector](https://github.com/hpgrahsl/kafka-connect-mongodb) in order to push data from Kafka to MongoDB

Configuration example for JSON with schema:

```
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true

value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
```

If you are using [Confluent Hub](https://www.confluent.io/hub/), you can find instructions on how to install the connector [here](https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-mongodb-sink/).